# Max Clause Count in ElasticSearch / Rewrite queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that ElasticSearch has an internal limit on how many clauses you can use in a bool query. This is controlled by the max_clause_count in the ElasticSearch.yml file.

But I thought that this limit did not apply to the values that were passed in the searches

So a query like the following would work, with more than 1024 values in the
terms query

```
{
        "query":{
            "bool":{
                "should":[
                    { "terms": {"id": ["cafe-babe-0000","cafe-babe-0001",... ]}}
                ] 
            }
        }
}
```

But this query will launch a TooManyClauses Exception. So, in this case, the
number of values in the query also counts for this limit. Is it correct?

Also, I now that it's not the best way to perform this kind of queries, but
Is it possible to rewrite the previous query so that the limit is not exceeded?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  [ids query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-ids-query.html).

```
"query": {
    "ids": {
        "values": [ "cafe-babe-0000","cafe-babe-0001",... ]
    }
}
```

For the best of i know there is no limitation on this query.